# Device Mac Randomization Android 11

Tags: mac-address, android-11

Does anyone know if there is a method to disable device mac randomization on a Samsung note 10,

The devices in question also have Android 11 which could be the problem,

This is not MAC Randomisation for WiFi, it is physical device MAC,

Currently this changes after every reboot of the system.

There does not seem to be a single mention of this issue anywhere that I can find but is causing an issue that needs a resolution one way or the other,

This causes a program that is essential to our business to not allow a registration to our services.

Thankyou in advance!

Cheers

Comment: How do you check the MAC address? From within an app or on network level (e.g. in a log of an WiFi access point)? If it is an app then you simply see a random number that has nothing to do with the actual MAC. On Android 11 apps simply can't acceess the MAC anymore.

Comment: Hi Robert, thankyou for responding! Well I suppose that answers my question, its strange though, when there is a MAC address through Wifi it can be static with randomisation switched off, this works perfectly fine, It just randomises persistently if there is no wifi enabled.

Comment: You still have not answered my question if you see the MAC from within an app or on network level. For Android 11 the MAC on network level should be the same as long as you connect to the same WiFi but you will only see that on network level from the "outside" of your phone.